# What is node_modules_bak?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I've got a folder in my project directory called 'node_modules_bak'. I don't know where it comes from or what it does. Google and StackOverflow do not provide any information about this name.

Does anyone know what it is and whether I can delete it safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a folder generated by `node` or `npm` or any well known tools.

It might be something generated internally by a script or even another developer wishing to backup the modules.

I would do a code search in all project files to see if the name comes up anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer mentions, there are some tools that create this directory. It is not created by `node` or `npm`.

In my case it was https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules/blob/0a009d670a4e4fcb185b29979b5f58668664da4b/src/helpers.js#L47-L49

```
  /* Check if node modules exist and then backup */
  let nodeModulesExist = fs.existsSync('node_modules')
  if (nodeModulesExist) fs.copySync('node_modules', 'node_modules_bak')
```

There are a couple more of these on github when I search across all repos https://github.com/search?q=node_modules_bak+language%3AJavaScript&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=JavaScript&l=